# getting fix number of TCP packets in java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am acquiring thousands of TCP packets. I read them one packet after one packet but I want to read them as whole of 128 packets after 128 packets. For the moment, I use

```
s = new Socket(ip, port);
byte[] buffer = new byte[some_length];
stream = s.getInputStream();
stream.read(buffer);
```

Precisely, each ordered sequence of 128 packets corresponds to one image (that will be reconstructed afterwards). By the way, the first byte of each TCP packet corresponds to a number between `1` and `128`, so that I can use these numbers as landmarks.

Is there a way, each time I get the first byte of a packet set to `1`, to read those packets by sequence of 128 without having to code a dedicated loop (this loop would call `128` times `stream.read(buffer);`) ?

Comment: Are you sure you will always receive 128 packet by image?? With TCP by default you doesn't choose when packet are sent

Comment: You are reading a stream of bytes, but you can call read for a certain number of bytes *if you know how many should be read*. Do you know?

Comment: @user43968 Yes I am sure I will receive 128 packets , each of which contains 2048 bytes if data

Comment: @laune I know precisely that each packet is 2048 bytes long

Comment: I assume you want all of the bytes in one `byte[]`. You may want something like `stream.read(buffer, 0, 128*2048)`. Edit: You'd have to adjust for having already read the first byte to look for `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You state in the comments that every packet is exact 2048 bytes long, while the amount of this number isn't important, important is that the length is fixed.

There are different methods of reading fixed length packets:

## Using `InputStream.read` in a loop

A call to `InputStream.read` may not fill the buffer fully, it may fill only 1 byte, even if you requested more. To counter this, you need to read in a while loop.

```
public byte[] readImage(InputStream in, int imageLength) throw IOException{
    byte[] out = new byte[imageLength];
    int read;
    for(int i = 0; read = in.read(out, i, imageLength - i); i += read) 
        if(read < 0)
             throw new EOFException();
    return out;
}
```

In the loop above, we are first allocating a byte array of the required size, then we are calling `in.read` with our byte array and the current index. This way, we are sure we never return a half read packet to our caller

## Using [`DataInput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html)

Instead of manually reinventing the wheel, you can also use [`DataInput.readFully`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readFully(byte%5B%5D)) to read the byte array fully. This is easy:

```
byte[] image = new byte[imagelength];
DataInput in = new DataInputStream(inStream);
in.readFully(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how I proceed

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(stream);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
    while(buffer[0] !=1){
        dis.readFully(buffer);
    }

    byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[len]; 
    byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[nb_line * len];
    int count_lines = 0;

    while(true){
        dis.readFully(tmpBuffer);
        System.arraycopy(tmpBuffer, 1, finalBuffer, (count_lines + 1) * rows, rows);
        count_lines++;
        if(count_lines == 127)
            break;
    }
```